# Question about .h @interface in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the text inside parentheses in @interface and @implementation directives mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378479/what-does-the-text-inside-parentheses-in-interface-and-implementation-directiv)

I've seen many interfaces' look like this

`@interface UIView`

but everyonce in a while I will come across one that looks like so

`@interface UIView (ObjectTagAdditions)`

Could someone please explain to me what (ObjectTagAdditions) is, and what affect it could have in the actual code?

Sorry for the noob question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search for "Categories in Objective C"

Perfect beginner post with example [here](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html)

Answer (score 0):

ObjectTagAdditions is a Category.  When you use that syntax in an interface, you're adopting the methods defined for that category (likely hence the "Additions" part of that identifier).

You can extend the behavior on classes similar to extension methods in .NET.

[Objective C Categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html)