# Interface syntax with + sign (UIView+AdditionalFeatures.h)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I'm looking through a lot of open source code I have noticed that there are some .h/.m files with a different naming convention. I have seen it in multiple places so there must be some logic or functionality behind it. I have seen them name something like UIImage+AdditionalFeatures.h/UIImage+AdditionalFeatures.m. What does the '+' between the two words in those titles represent? I created a new file with that naming convention, but in the .h it just puts an underscore(_) in place of the +:

```
@interface UIImage_AdditionalFeatures
```

All of the files that I've seen use it have a format that looks like:

```
@interface UIImage (AdditionalFeatures)
```

When I attempted to change my title to the same format that I've seen elsewhere I can warnings and errors.

What does this naming convention mean and what is the proper way to implement it?

Comment: Look up the Objective-C concept of class categories.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the text inside parentheses in \@interface and \@implementation directives mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378479/what-does-the-text-inside-parentheses-in-interface-and-implementation-directiv), among [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+@interface+with+parentheses).

Comment: Sorry for the possible duplicate. I did a lot of searching to find the answer, but I had absolutely no idea what to search for exactly. I wasn't finding any useful results so I figured that I'd ask. Thank you for the responses!

Comment: I would say the question is distinct from the proposed duplicate. It is true a better understanding of categories would have made it clear, but the question is distinct, and reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention you are observing is what is typically done with [Objective-C categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

It is convention, though not an explicit requirement of categories to name the file with the name of the class the category is being applied to, and then the `+`, followed by the name of the category itself.

Notice that the `+` is not added to the actual `@interface` of the category, it is merely in the file name.